# CentOS 7 with KDE: Session bus not found

Tags: centos, kde

While using git on my newly installed CentOS 7 with KDE, I get the following error:

```
ksshaskpass(15344)/kdeui (kdelibs): Session bus not found 
To circumvent this problem try the following command (with Linux and bash) 
export $(dbus-launch) 
error: /usr/bin/ksshaskpass died of signal 6
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/bin/ksshaskpass'
```

However this does not interfere with the execution of the git commands. Any leads on why this might be happening?

UPDATE: I did go ahead and gave the `export $(dbus-launch)` command before running `git clone` again. Turns out this error was holding behind the launch of the KDE wallet with a somewhat buggy interface. Will try and report it to the right team.